# Need a Combobox binding issue fix

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, combobox

Hello. I'm learning C# and WPF plz add your code in my code then I can easily understand. I'm `Binding` a `CombBox` in WPF using C# code, I need did have fix on thing in this code 
which I didnt able to find what i can wright in my code more.

```
string sql = "SELECT " + ColumnsValue + "," + ColumnsName + " FROM " + TableName;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, Connection);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();                
da.Fill(ds, TableName);
ComboBox.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
ComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = ds.Tables[0].Columns[ColumnsName].ToString();
ComboBox.SelectedValuePath = ds.Tables[0].Columns[ColumnsValue].ToString(); 
// Some Code here to to fix this
ComboBox.Selected = "--Select--";
```

I need a help to fix it how can i use a `Select` value as a selected value on the top of `ComboBox`. I hope some buddy have a Solution for fix it.

Comment: You will have to create your own source using the Tables[0].DefaultView plus an element for your "--Select--" field. Add them together into one collection and use this as your itemssource.

Comment: Can you please write to in my code i did get exactly how can..

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you exactly

Comment: Create a new collection, add everything from your database query to it, and add as a first element a string with "--Select--" now set this as your ItemsSource. Depending on how complex your DataTemplate is, you need to provide two different DataTemplates one for your data and one for the Select item. That is as clear as i can put it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Default Value For ComboBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443169/set-default-value-for-combobox)

Comment: I want to do this with code which i wrote over there.

Answer (score 0):

You Can create new Object of Table named as defaultTable
and assign 
defaultTable.ColumnName  = "--Selected--"
defaultTable.ColumnValue = 0 (if columnValue is int else "0" if columnValue is string)
ComboBox.Insert(0, defaultTable);

and then bind ItemSource.
Hope this helps u.

Comment: we can use this in simple windows application forms i don't think  it will same use in wpf please see my code clearly..

Comment: It works for me in WPF in code behind.
You can bind Combobox ItemsSource in .xaml file 
as ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxName}"

Answer (score 0):

This is one answer found in stackoverflow.

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443169/set-default-value-for-combobox)

And some options are

1. If you are using code behind file, you can do something like below code snippets.

   ```
   myComboBox.Items.Insert(0, "--Select Item--");

   myComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
   ```
2. You can use value converters

Please look at this [post](http://graemehill.ca/nullable-combo-boxes-in-wpf/) to use the value converters

Comment: I try this before too not working in WPF read my code or try it in wpf  test project you can know that well :)